# SQL UPDATE A COLUMN = 'XYZ' WHERE SELECT (MULTIPLE ROWS TO UPDATE COMPARING DIFFERENT TABLE)

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

BELOW SQL GIVES -811 OR JOB GET CANCELLED

```
 UPDATE RATES A                 
 SET A.D_PROC_RATE_END  = '1234'          
  WHERE EXISTS                                  
  (                                            
 SELECT A.C_PROCEDURE,                          
        A.C_SPECIALTY,                          
        A.C_PROV_TYPE,                          
        A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD,                      
        A.N_PROC_RATE                           
   FROM PROC B                 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  RATES A      

 ON                                             
    A.C_SPECIALTY     = '181'                
AND A.C_PROV_TYPE     = B.C_PROV_TYPE        
AND A.C_PROCEDURE     = B.C_PROCEDURE        
AND (A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD = B.C_PROCEDURE_MOD   
   OR A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD IS NULL)           
AND (A.D_PROC_RATE_END  IS NULL              
OR  A.D_PROC_RATE_END  = '12/31/9999')      
AND A.N_PROC_RATE     = B.N_PROC_RATE        
ORDER BY A.C_PROCEDURE)
```

WILL THIS sql NOT UPDATE EVERY RECORD CONTAIING BELOW CRITERIA?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T WRITE IN **ALL CAPS**! It's considered **SHOUTING** at people, it's rude and unwelcome - please fix your post!

Comment: Which DB2 platform please?  Did you not look up the SQLCODE?  It's complaining about getting multiple rows... which shouldn't be a problem with `WHERE EXISTS()` (since it looks for _any_ rows, not 'just' one).  Is this really your query?  You're also using the same table alias in the inner and outer queries - while this _does_ work, it makes it difficult to tell what columns are where.  If you're trying to compare columns from the inner and outer queries, it's going to ignore the outer table reference.  And the `ORDER BY` is unnecessary.

Comment: sorry, I appologise for that, had caps on in mainframe, you know DB2 strings in text are caps sensitive :(

Comment: Clockwork-Muse thanks.. actually this query updated every row in the table.
its a big mess up now.

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer whether it will update every row or not. We don't know the data. If the EXISTS() predicate returns a 'true' value each time, then it will update every row; otherwise it won't.

Run this query first:

```
 SELECT A.C_PROCEDURE,                          
        A.C_SPECIALTY,                          
        A.C_PROV_TYPE,                          
        A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD,                      
        A.N_PROC_RATE                           
   FROM RATES A                 
  WHERE EXISTS                                  
  (                                            
 SELECT A.C_PROCEDURE,                          
        A.C_SPECIALTY,                          
        A.C_PROV_TYPE,                          
        A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD,                      
        A.N_PROC_RATE                           
   FROM PROC B                 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  RATES A      

 ON                                             
    A.C_SPECIALTY     = '181'                
AND A.C_PROV_TYPE     = B.C_PROV_TYPE        
AND A.C_PROCEDURE     = B.C_PROCEDURE        
AND (A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD = B.C_PROCEDURE_MOD   
   OR A.C_PROCEDURE_MOD IS NULL)           
AND (A.D_PROC_RATE_END  IS NULL              
OR  A.D_PROC_RATE_END  = '12/31/9999')      
AND A.N_PROC_RATE     = B.N_PROC_RATE        
ORDER BY A.C_PROCEDURE)
```

Every row that is returned is one that would be updated. (I almost always run a test SELECT before I do any non-trivial UPDATEs.)

You can run the test SELECT query after changing it to say `WHERE`**NOT**`EXISTS` to see which would NOT be updated.